# GPS android requestLocationUpdate

Tags: android, gps

I have a class named `GPSSampleLocation`

There is a function to turn on gps and based on that getting location

here gpsEnabled will be true but in my phone when I request for gps the GPS icon on above in my PHONE will be blinking ... but it is not blinking also... and I am not getting data

```
public void getGPSLocation() {
    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) GPSSampleLocation.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean gpsEnabled = mlocManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnabled) {
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(
                getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                    "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
    gpsEnabled = mlocManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    System.out.println("GPS ENALBLE" + gpsEnabled);
    if (gpsEnabled) {
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                GPSSampleLocation.this);
    }
}
```

I have also used these permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: GPS may not work in building and GPS is slow process to get locations

Comment: ya abhi but it should be blinking!!! it's also not blinking icon on top of notification area...

Comment: Download [GPS Test](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chartcross.gpstest&hl=en) and wait till you get a fix. You can then try and see if your app is able to get the location.

Comment: If the icon is not blinking then go to Settins->Location & Security and check the "Use GPS Satellites" check box.

Comment: ya it is enabled and still it is not blinking if it is blinking than i will be sure that i will get location

Comment: Your code doesnt show a listener. You need a LocationListener to receive the location updates

Comment: no TanjaV i have listener but i have not written overhere

Comment: I can only assume that you do not have enough GPS signal. check pls if other apps work, such as google maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is my code to test RequestLocationUpdates and LocationManager and LocationListener.

```
package com.test.locationmanager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocationManagerStatus extends Activity {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private TextView textView;

    private final LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "GPS available again\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "GPS out of service\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "GPS temporarily unavailable\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "GPS Provider Enabled\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "GPS Provider Disabled\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);

            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "New GPS location: "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLatitude()) + ", "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLongitude()) + "\n");

        }
    };

    private final LocationListener networkLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "Network location available again\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "Network location out of service\n");
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "Network location temporarily unavailable\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "Network Provider Enabled\n");

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "Network Provider Disabled\n");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + "New network location: "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLatitude()) + ", "
                    + String.format("%9.6f", location.getLongitude()) + "\n");

        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, networkLocationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, gpsLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);
    }
}
```